# How can I get the values of an Object type in my Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, model, casting

I have a Model with an item of type `object` called `myobject`:

```
public class myModel
{
    public long id {get;set;}
    public object myobject {get;set;}
}
```

in my View I use `EditorFor` to edit the `myobject` with a template:

```
@model myModel
// form (code omitted)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myobject)

<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

This is the template:

```
@model myObject

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myname)
```

How can I get the `myModel.myobject` value in the controller? 
I've tried to cast but I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'MyProject.Models.myobject'.

Comment: You get that by default in a controllers action using Model.XXXX

Comment: can you post the code of your controller?

Comment: public PartialViewResult Save (myModel model)
{
    // Here I need model.myobject!!!
}

Comment: yes, but the line that's causing the exception

Comment: The exception is caused by: myObject myItem = (myObject)myModel.myobject;

Comment: @Luca, myObject is not a type, that shouldn't compile

Comment: Luca, are you sure you haven't mixed up 'myObject' with 'myModel' in a few places in your question?

Answer (score 1):

The property in the model is of type `object`:

```
public object myobject { get; set; }
```

Your EditorTemplate is of type `myObject` - NOT of type `object`:

```
@model myObject <-- This little thing is responsible telling MVC what editor template to use with which type.

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myname)
```

This is why you aren't getting the implementation you're looking for.

As an alternative you can use a **named** EditorTemplate instead of letting MVC infer what template you want based on the type.